# How to change textFieldFor input to radioButtons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, input

in my project (asp .net mvc) I have a class... for that class I create or edit records through inputs, it's obvious. My problem is that I would like to change this textBoxfor in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dostupnost: [1/0]</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dostupnost, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Dostupnost)
    </div>
</div>
```

to radio buttons with same functionality. Property is `int` with range from **0-2**, so 3 buttons, does anybody have some idea? thank you.

I replace previous text box with:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dostupnost</label>
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

but waht now? I just need little pust with condition :)

solution: Thanks everybody

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dostupnost:</label>
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Dostupnost, 1)Dostupná
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Dostupnost, 0)Nedostupná
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. textbox and radiobutton are different controls. How do you expect radio buttons to display the textbox data?

Comment: @ViVi I need something like... if is selected  button one the value of property is 0... if button 2 value is 1... do you understand now? :)

Comment: Where do you want to display the values? Do you want to bind the radio button to some string property in model? Do you want to pass the values '0','1' and '2' to the controller when user submits the data?

Comment: @ViVi with this form I create record which is saved to database. And it is int property which I want to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code

Radio buttom Razer view is

```
 <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.Dostupnost, 0, new { name = "Dostupnost"})Option 1</label>
 <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.Dostupnost, 1, new { name = "Dostupnost" })Option 2</label>
 <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.Dostupnost, 2, new { name = "Dostupnost" })Option 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlHelper`

```
@Html.RadioButton("RadioButton","0")
@Html.RadioButton("RadioButton","1")
@Html.RadioButton("RadioButton","2")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you should add a list that hold your option value and display text. For example,
that list will be defined like this

```
  object[] DostupnostList = new object[] { {Id: 1, Name: "Text 1"}, 
             {Id: 2, Name: "Text 2"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Text 3"} };
```

Then in Razor code, you could bind your Dostupnost property to a radio list like the following

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dostupnost: [1/0]</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @foreach(var option in Model.DostupnostList) 
        {
            @Html.RadiobuttonFor(x => x.Dostupnost, option.Id)
            @Html.Label(x => x.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Dostupnost)
        }         
    </div>
</div>
```